# Sybase to SSIS connection error

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ssis, sybase

i am trying to connect to sybase using SSIS for last 5 days but i am not being able to. I have posted it before [My PROBLEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828043/connect-sybase-to-ssis) but no one seems to have to solution. May be i need some other dirver or something. this is what i am doing to connect to sybase. plz help.

1. I INSTALLED SYBASE ASE 15
2. OPENED INTERACTIVE SQL TO CREATE A NEW DATABASE AND SOME TABLES IN IT.
3. CREATED A NEW SSIS PROJECT IN VISUAL STUDIO 2008
4. ADDED A NEW 'Data Flow Task'
5. ADDED A NEW OLE DB SOURCE
6. DOUBLE CLICK ON NEW OLE DB SOURCE AND CLICKED THE NEW
7. UNDER THE PROVIDER I SELECTED 'Sybase OLEDB Provider'
   8.[image]
8. ENTERED THE SERVER NAME AND PASSWORD

now i get this error...plz help me out. AM I MISSING ANY STEP HERE???

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a solution to the problem.

Instead of adding a 'OLE DB Source' from Data Flow Sources i added an 'ADO NET Source',
then create an 'Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise Data Provider'

[image]

Filled in the details of the Sybase Server Credentials.[image]

AND finally i had all the tables i created on the Sybase ASE server.

[image]